# Pipes vibrating - even when valve closed

Tags: plumbing, noise

I came home to a loud buzzing noise today. I realised it was the toilet. I gave it a quick look over, and nothing seemed wrong.

As I investigated further, I realised the toilet has its own separate mains line feeding it (and only it). All other taps etc. in the flat are supplied from a separate inlet.

I could feel the buzzing on the mains line feeding the toilet, so I found the stopcock and closed it, and emptied the toilet tank. The buzzing actually got *worse* when I did this (and became more like knocking).

Is the problem likely with the plumbing outside my property (I live in a block of flats, 1930's), or is there anything else I can do to find/fix the problem myself?

Comment: That is strange with no water flow you are experiencing water hammer. I have heard water hammer from small leaks at just the right flow that was quite loud. Plumbing stores have arestors that can be added after the stopcock that may help for 10-20$.

Comment: Are you sure there is no water flowing into the toilet now, while the knocking continues? If so, then the source isn't the toilet.

Comment: @DanielGriscom Yeah, the problem is upstream, over to building maintenance >.<